# Limit the training job time for users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

As AWS administrator, how I can limit the sagemaker instances running ti me for users. SO, each user can run notebook instances or training job for a specified limited time.?

Thanks in advance

I could limit the instance type using IAM roles but have no idea to how to control the running time for notebook and training jobs time

Answer (score 0):

You can use life cycle configuration under sagemaker notebook instance and me tion cron job specifications

Answer (score 0):

For SageMaker notebook instances, you can use Life cycle configuration script as mentioned by @yashaswi k.

For SageMaker training jobs, you can use parameter "MaxRuntimeInSeconds" in Stopping Condition: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_StoppingCondition.html